# When are equivalent TOST test possible?

Tags: t-test, equivalence, tost

For my end-of-study work in architecture, i am comparing different reconstruction (~10) distances from  reference 3D model.

I'd like to test if reconstruction are different using statistical tests.
On independent, random and simple normal samples I'd like to do those tests :

1. Krustall Wallis test, to test if median of the 10 different reconstruction are different,
2. Dunn's test, with bonferroni p adjusted values to check which reconstruction combination are different
3. F test, to check if variance are different,
4. Welch TOST equivalence t-test to check if mean is included in a given interval ( let's say +-1 cm).

My question is: is it possible to make a TOST using Welch’s t-test ? I've saw it nowhere on the net, and i'd like to know if it is possible to create one using  Welch’s t-test.

I plan to adapt this function in python :
https://gist.github.com/josef-pkt/3900314
and replace `ttest_1samp` with `ttest_ind`.

Comment: If your data are approximately normally distributed, why are you using the Kruskal-Wallis test, rather than one way ANOVA and *post hoc  t* tests? And if your data are *not* approximately normally distributed, why are you proposing to use Welch's *t* test in TOST?

Comment: My data is approximately normally distributed, I just haven't thought of one way ANOVA. Seems much easier that way. What are the post hoc t test you mention ?

Is Welch's t test in TOST only applicable to approximately normally distributed dataset ?

Comment: *Post hoc t* tests are akin to Dunn's test: they use a pooled variance implied by the ANOVA's null hypothesis. In general *t* tests assume approximately normally distributed data.

Comment: Thanks; i'll replace Krustall Wallis and Dunn's test with anova and post hoc t test. Seem much appropriate to my dataset

Answer (score 0):

I am far from knowledgeable in TOST, but the implementation of 2 sample TOST in the TOASTER R package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TOSTER/TOSTER.pdf (page 9) has a parameter whether the variances are equal or not. So I would guess that it is OK to use Welch.

dataTOSTtwo(
data,
deps,
group,
var_equal = FALSE,

Comment: Thanks, seem pretty legit ! As far as i understand, TOST is only a dubble t test with low and up boundary, so i don't see why it won't work